# Morphism from complete variety to an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, affine-varieties

I am working on Mumfords Abelian Varieties and am not 100% familiar with varieties yet.
In some proof it is used that any morphism from a complete variety to an affine variety is constant. I could not find any references on that.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: We can assume that the affine variety is $\mathbb A^n$ (by composition with the affine embedding). Now we get a morphism to $\mathbb P^n$ not meeting the hyperplane at infinity. By properness the image is closed, and if the dimension is positive it needs to meet every hyperplane, so the image is of dimension $0$.